# jQuery click event error: "TypeError: cannot call method 'toString' on undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error on my jQuery script:

```
$("input.buttonConfirmOrder").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do some stuff with the order
    return false;
});
```

The error pops up in an alertbox:

> TypeError: cannot call method 'toString' on undefined

I'm not using `toString` at any point, and the error pops up as soon as I click the link, that is before hitting the first line of the function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

The button calling the event looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$ButtonConfirmOrder" value="Pay" id="ctl00_mainContent_ButtonConfirmOrder" class="buttonConfirmOrder confirmButton">
```

I've tried all of the following:

- `$("input.buttonConfirmOrder").on("click", function(e) { /...`
- `$ = jQuery;`
- `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: looks like it works http://jsfiddle.net/T2d24/

Comment: Why do you have a `submit` that's not supposed to submit? Why not a `button` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector doesn't match the CSS class on your button. It should be:

```
$("input.buttonConfirmOrderDIBS").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do some stuff with the order
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the problem. I just made a mistake in posting the code block. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle to check this and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/picklespy/rZ4ZT/2/

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$ButtonConfirmOrder" value="Pay"
        id="ctl00_mainContent_ButtonConfirmOrder"
         class="buttonConfirmOrder confirmButton">
```

Javascript:

```
$("input.buttonConfirmOrder").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).val())
    //do some stuff with the order
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve the problem. This is an exact copy of my code. Which makes the problem even more mysterious...

Comment: @kumaheiyama In that case, the issue might be that the `javascript` code is running before the html `button` in the html. Please make sure the javascript code runs after the button code is declared in the html. Put this piece of code before the closing body tag.

Comment: No, there's no code running after the body tag. But it's very possible that the problem occurs because of some code running previous to my jquery script. It's wierd though that it occurs only when pressing the button and not for instance while loading the page.

Comment: That's not what i mean. Put your js before the closing body tag. That way, your js will correctly find the `button` reference in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose is to prevent default submit action. Then add an attribute `onsubmit=return false;` to the container form of the submit button. No need of doing `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: As I wrote, the problem is not the e.preventDefault(). The error occurs before that code is even run, but rather as soon as the button is pressed.